# what does =~ in linux means used in if condition to compare values

Tags: linux, shell-script, tomcat, conditional-statements

Actually `tomcat/conf/catalina.properties` file contains line `shared.loader=/usr/share/sfit/conf` I mean value has some path.

so using shell script we are updating `shared.loader` values in file. And also there is a if condition which compares value it is like

```
if [ $string1 =~ $string2 ] ; then
```

here `=~` what does it mean.

and also I want delete the value from line "shared.loader=" what ever it contains after `shared.loader=`

please help me out guys

Comment: `=~` is a binary operator, when it's used the string to the right is considered an extended regular expression.

Comment: well could someone help me out deleting the string "value" from the line share.loader="value" from a file catalina.properties

Comment: There's nothing Linux specific about this question I think. You could perhaps tag it with apache and bash or something. Also, just edit the question if you want to change/refine it (since there are no answers, if there were then you should ask a new question). Also, some other site like unix.stachexchange.com might be better for help in writing shell scripts like this.

Comment: What shell are you using? In bash, `=~` works only in double `[[ ... ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

```
sed -ie 's,^shared.loader=\(.*\)value_to_remove\(.*\),shared.loader=\1\2,' tomcat/conf/catalina.properties
```

Explanation:

- "-i" means "replace file contents". MUST BE OMITTED WHILE TESTING!
- "-e" means "expression applied to each line". Optional here.
- "s,mask,newval," means "search and replace".
- `\1` is replaced to contents of first `(.*)`, `\2` to contents of second `(.*)`.